# Python Reference Language: nonlocal definition

Tags: python, scope

In [this paragraph](https://docs.python.org/dev/reference/simple_stmts.html#nonlocal), one can find the following sentence (my emphasis):

> Names listed in a nonlocal statement, unlike those listed in a global statement, must refer to pre-existing bindings in an enclosing scope (**the scope in which a new binding should be created cannot be determined unambiguously**).

I take the bold-ed sentence in the parenthesis to explain the previous sentence meaning that in order for a nonlocal statement such as `nonlocal a` to be correct, a statement such as `a = 1` should have problems deciding in what namespace to add (or modify) the binding, either in the local namespace or in an enclosing namespace (because there exists such a namespace already containing the binding for name `a`).

Is this correct, is that the intention?

If yes, I believe that the wording (in the parenthesis) would hold even for cases in which `a` is global, as "the scope in which a new binding should be created cannot be determined unambiguously", which is not intended. Am I correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The language reference is saying that some statement in an outer scope must create the variable for `nonlocal` to refer to. For example, this is fine:

```
def f():
    def g():
        a = 3
        def h():
            def i():
                nonlocal a
                print(a)
```

but this is not:

```
def f():
    def g():
        def h():
            def i():
                nonlocal a
                print(a)
```

because in the first snippet, Python can tell that `nonlocal` should use the `a` variable from the `g` function. In the second snippet, Python would have to create a new `a` variable in one of the enclosing functions, and it can't tell which.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, and I think the first part of the sentence explained that clearly: "Names listed in a nonlocal statement, unlike those listed in a global statement, **must refer to pre-existing bindings in an enclosing scope**". I was wondering about the correctness of the rest of the sentence: " (the scope in which a new binding should be created cannot be determined unambiguously).".

Comment: @user42768: The parenthesized part is saying that if there is no existing binding, Python would have to create a new one, and it can't tell where to do that.

Comment: I don't see how you're getting "a statement such as a = 1 should have problems deciding in what namespace to add (or modify) the binding" out of it. Assignment statements aren't nonlocal statements, and don't use the same rules.

Comment: I found this: "The following constructs bind names: formal parameters to functions, import statements, class and function definitions (these bind the class or function name in the defining block), and **targets that are identifiers if occurring in an assignment** [...]". Therefore I believe assignment statements create bindings. As for the wording, if that was the meaning, why doesn't it say: "[...] must refer to pre-existing bindings in an enclosing scope. The statement is illegal if the scope cannot be determined unambiguously."?

Comment: @user42768: Assignments create bindings, but for those, Python can tell where to create them: in the scope of the assignment. It can't do that for `nonlocal`.

Comment: @user42768 Look at the second example. Since `a` hasn't been defined outside of the local scope of `i`, where should it be created? In `h`, `g`, or `f`? There's no way to tell what the user's intent was. With `global`, there's no issue because there's only one global scope.

Comment: @user2357112 Unless I misunderstood you, in this code: https://trinket.io/python3/00d09b0092 the assignment in f affects the binding of the outer scope (g).

Comment: @user2357112 Ok, I re-read the sentence and now I understand the wording. I still believe that altering it to say: "Names listed in a nonlocal statement, unlike those listed in a global statement, must refer to pre-existing bindings in an enclosing scope (**[if this condition is not met,]** the scope in which a new binding should be created cannot be determined unambiguously).". Is this the intended meaning? Thank you very much.